# Ubuntu 20.04: Could not get owner of name 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties': no such name

Tags: 20.04, permissions

I'm trying to open software-properties-gtk to view my additional drivers for debugging a completely separate issue and I'm receiving this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
    return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  

File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 208, in __init__
    proxy = bus.get_object("com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties", "/")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 277, in start_service_by_name
    return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

I've seen a suggestion of installing aptitude and reinstall dbus, I attempted this though it didn't work even after rebooting my system.

Answer (score 3):

The mentioned *com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties* is [contained in two packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties), so you have to reinstall both

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
```

and then retry to start `software-properties-gtk`.

Comment: No dice, same error unfortunately.

Comment: Also try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-dbus` and make sure that you are using default built-in python 3.8.10.

Comment: I had removed the gtk installation of software-properties and went with qt instead, seems to have solved it. Earlier the python -V was returning 3.9, troubled I traced it back to my anaconda instance while my system still uses 3.8. Reinstalling python3-dbus wasn't fully tested if it would've helped with the gtk lib.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time ago, but here's my solution, just in case some one needs it.

Run `sudo systemctl status dbus.`
You can see some errors there. We need to solve them in order to activate service 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties' or any other service.

Eg: In my case

- No dbus_bindings. Solution: Go to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` and
  create link to your `_dbus_bindings` and `_dbus_glib_bindings`.

`sudo ln -s _dbus_glib_bindings.cpython-***.so _dbus_glib_bindings.cpython.so`

and so on.

- No _gi module: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60352723

Finally, you can recheck dbus status, and it should be like this: Successfully activated service '***'.

Comment: And @thomas-ward, a moderator, I  don't know why he did delete my previous answer. Did he check the result before doing that? I just don't want to re-type all this text again.