# org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.debian.apt': no such name

Tags: 20.04, python, update-manager, dbus

I have missed up with my python3 version in Ubuntu `20.04`, and after calling `$ update-manager` I'm getting the following Error, can you please tell me how can I fix that

P.S: I have tried some [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1396842), but they didn't work in my case.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 173, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 348, in get_name_owner
    return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 634, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.debian.apt': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 479, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1623, in _run_transaction_helper
    daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1709, in get_aptdaemon
    return dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.debian.apt",
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 237, in get_object
    return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 178, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 273, in start_service_by_name
    return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 634, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 173, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 348, in get_name_owner
    return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 634, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.debian.apt': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 479, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1623, in _run_transaction_helper
    daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1709, in get_aptdaemon
    return dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.debian.apt",
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 237, in get_object
    return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 178, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 273, in start_service_by_name
    return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 634, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1594, in on_error
    error.raise_exception()
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 125, in raise_exception
    raise self.type(self.value).with_traceback(self.traceback)
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 479, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1623, in _run_transaction_helper
    daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1709, in get_aptdaemon
    return dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.debian.apt",
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 237, in get_object
    return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 178, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 273, in start_service_by_name
    return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 634, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 390, in _next
    self.result = callback(self.result, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1596, in on_error
    error_handler(error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/errors.py", line 196, in <lambda>
    get_native_exception(err))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/errors.py", line 211, in get_native_exception
    dbus_msg = error.get_dbus_message()
  File "/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/exceptions.py", line 82, in get_dbus_message
    s = ''.join(self.args)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, DBusException found
```

Comment: You need to restore the default python.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did already, but this is the aftermath.

Comment: See if `sudo apt install --reinstall python3` solves it?

Comment: @Raffa I have already done that, but still the error the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's been long time, but here's my solution.

1. Run `sudo systemctl status dbus`.
2. You can see some errors there. We need to solve them in order to activate service
   'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties' or any other service.

Eg: In my case

1. No dbus_bindings.

Solution: Go to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` and create link to your `_dbus_bindings` and `_dbus_glib_bindings`.

`sudo ln -s _dbus_glib_bindings.cpython-***.so _dbus_glib_bindings.so` and so on.

2. No _gi module: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60352723

Finally you can check dbus status again, and it should be like this: `Successfully activated service '***'`

In your case:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VFlO.png)